# Disable some of the TabIndex values on Form Controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form with 27 controls, but I need the tab key to cycle between only four of these controls. Every time the tab key is pressed, it should only move the focus between these 4 controls.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `TabIndex` of the controls you wish to navigate through. For the others, set `TabStop` to false.

Answer (score 1):

This article describes how to set the tab index on Windows Forms controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw(v=vs.90).aspx

According to that article, setting the `TabStop` property to `false`, on the controls that you want to be ignored by <kbd>TAB</kbd>, should achieve your objective.

For the 4 controls that you do want to be affected by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>, use the `TaxbIndex` property to set the values from 0 to 3.